# OLS AR (1) -GARCH (1,1) process

Tags: time-series, likelihood, garch

Obtain the log-likelihood function for the process AR (1) -GARCH (1,1)

$ y_t = µ + φy_{t−1} + ε_t$

$ε_t = σ_t(Ψ)z_t$

$σ^2_t = α_0 + α_1ε^2_{t−1} + βσ^2_{t−1}$

Where $z_t$∼ N(0, 1).

How can I get the Log OLS?

Comment: Welcome to this site. If this is homework, please add the [tag:self-study] tag and review its wiki in order to get better guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by *Log OLS*?